# Transclusión de contenido angular

Tags: angular6

ola quisiera lograr lo siguiente:

```
 <s-panel-edicion>
  <s-barra-lateral posicion="right" icono="fa fa-cog" [animar]="true"> </s-barra-lateral>
   <s-barra-lateral posicion="left" icono="fa fa-cog" [animar]="true"> </s-barra-lateral>
 </s-panel-edicion>
```

donde right y left son la posición de la barra lateral
esto es mi componente edicion:

```
<div class="container-plantilla">
   <div class="plantilla-template" [ngStyle]="moverBarraLeft">
     <ng-content select="s-barra-lateral"></ng-content>
   </div>
   <div class="plantilla-contenido" [ngClass]="{'plantilla-contenido-oculto':!displayLeft,'plantilla-contenido-no-oculto':displayLeft,'plantilla-contenido-full':displayLeft}">
     <ng-content select="s-contenido"></ng-content>
   </div>
   <div class="plantilla-template" [ngStyle]="moverBarraRight">
      <ng-content select="s-barra-lateral"></ng-content>
   </div>
</div>
```

solo se muestra un lado 
alguien me oriente como puedo lograr eso agradeceré su ayuda
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

deseo lograr lo siguiente

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Pilar, realmente no entiendo lo que estás tratando de expresar, podrías ser más específica en lo que esperas obtener.

Comment: adjunte imagen de lo que quiero lograr es transclusion de contenido algo a como hace primeng sus componentes

Comment: Ok, haber si entiendo: 1. estás usando *PrimeNG* para tu diseño web, 2. Requieres un sidebar doble, tanto en el lado izquierdo como en el derecho; o lo que requieres es un unico sidebar pero que se muestre en ambos lados según la desicion del usuario? o estás tratando de realizar la misma función de *PrimeNG* con tu propio código (CSS, SASS, SCSS, etc.)

Comment: la opcion 2 es correcta los laterales vienen a ser paneles de configuración que aceptaran cualquier contenido. vienen a ser un solo componente <s-panel-edicion>.  ya que tengo varias estructuras parecidas y quiero reutilizar, teniendo en cuenta que el contenido es variado solo la estructura es repetida

Comment: Podrías adjuntar lo que tienes declarado en tu componente sobre el atributo de la directiva NgStyle --**moverBarraRight**

Comment: moverBarraRight =  event.posicion === 'left' ?  'left': '0em' } : { 'left': '-17em' }   define el movimiento de los paneles para ocultar el problema es que solo se crea un panel.